# Choose one result in Splunk table Query

Tags: splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

1. I would like to add radio button / any way to select - one of the results of my below REST query search,

QUERY :    |rest /services/data/ui/views | table id label updated "eai:userName" "eai:data" "eai:appName"

[Dashboard showing the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6OYM.png)

2. This Query search is saved as a dashboard (auto-refresh) and I have added few text boxes (User Name, Commit Branch, User Token) as show in the attached image. These text boxes will be manually filled by user.

Use Case: I need to choose any one row via radio button (or any other technical way) and then click on the SUBMIT button to send the selected row data and text box (manually entered by user) data to my custom python script.

What is the way to achieve this use case in Splunk, Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass results of a Dashboard elsewhere, you need to use a [drilldown](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Viz/DrilldownIntro)

See the [Dashboard XML](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/latest/Viz/PanelreferenceforSimplifiedXML) reference for more

Splunk will only send to a URL, however - so if you want it to go to a "custom python script", it will need to be accessible via URL

What does your "custom python script" do?